# Android "DataDroid" sample library - making multiple calls to WS using existing library

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've been able to hackily implement the [DataDroid](http://datadroid.foxykeep.com/presentation) library from Google's IO presentation in 2010 into my Android project, and it works great when I have a 1-1 `Activity` - `Request` relationship. However, in my `FilterSelectActivity` I need to make multiple calls to fill the drop-down boxes on my view so the user can select filters. The problem is that the way the library is structured it is not immediately obvious how to make multiple (distinct) calls to the WS using the existing library/callbacks. In particular, I can setup my own `callThisMethodWS` functions, but there's only one `onRequestFinished` signature:

`public void onRequestFinished(final int requestId, final int resultCode, final Bundle payload)`

Now, the `requestId` is a pseudorandom `int` that is generated by the specific calling function, so it indicates a "unique" request in terms of its parameters but certainly not a specific request type. `resultCode` is of no use and I'm not sure what I could do with `Bundle` other than maybe grabbing an intent extra.

If anyone has implemented `DataDroid` in their project with multiple WS calls in one activity I would like to know how you differentiated the requests so you could fill your various `ArrayLists` or `ArrayAdapters`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of DataDroid and I've since then released version 2 of datadroid with allows  much more easily to send multiple requests from a single Activity or Fragment.

I've also added a new sample ([DoubleListActivity](https://github.com/foxykeep/DataDroid/blob/master/DataDroidPoC/src/com/foxykeep/datadroidpoc/ui/ws/DoubleListActivity.java) in the sample project) which calls 2 webservices from the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by setting up some constants in the class to identify request types, create a request type member, set that member to the specific constant in each respective WS call, then use that request type member in a conditional in the processing of the result.

Comment: I'm looking into that lib.  Have you found it useful/recommend?

Comment: I am by no means an authority in Android stuff, but as a beginner I was able to accomplish the necessary REST client functionality pretty neatly using DataDroid and following their sample app structure to a t (or pretty closely, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

In my app I needed something like this too. I have a lot of activities than can have multiple calls to WS, some have more than 5 or 6 differents calls to handle.

To implement this behavior, I added a `Request` object that contains the request type and the default `onRequestFinished` callback, that will call `OnRequestSuccess, OnRequestError...` functions. Then I have an `Activity` with a `SparseArray` of Requests, that implements `OnRequestFinishedListener` and redirects everything to the correct Request. All my activities with WS calls inherit that `Activity`. I recently implemented this for fragments too.